# Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit - StartException

Tags: java, web-applications, jboss7.x

I am quite new to web applications but I'm trying to fix an application that has worked previously, using my (very) basic understanding of web applications. This application has been built by someone else who I can no longer ask for help. I hope that you can point me in the right direction. After several days of use of Google I still haven't found a solution.

I am using Jboss 7 and the jboss-eap Runtime Server that is provided. Installed JDK is 1.7.0_60 (due to other program who refuses to work with a newer version...); however, I get the same problem with JDK 1.8.0_20. I also use Maven 3.0.4 and Hibernate (can't find which version).

The application seems to deploy almost completely, but at the end I get a StartException error and several causes (Nullpointers and IllegalState). I am not sure where to look. Is something wrong with the Hibernate configurations or is it a different problem?

Any help is greatly appreciated! If you need more information, just ask.
(as I am quite new, I hope you could be quite specific about where to look for certain files etc if applicable).

Regards,
Century

Exception stack:

(I've changed some names to 'test' for privacy reasons)

```
13:41:55,745 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
13:41:56,354 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
13:41:56,593 WARN  [org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): test.model.Class1
13:41:56,594 WARN  [org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): test.model.Class2
13:41:56,619 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
13:41:56,631 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
13:41:56,751 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.1.Final-redhat-1
13:41:58,180 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.test.START: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".component.test.START: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:57) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.getComponentInstance(SingletonComponent.java:126)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.start(SingletonComponent.java:141)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:54) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
... 6 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:165)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:250)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:344)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.java:66)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at test.process.test.init(test.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptorFactory.java:130) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionInterceptor.java:73)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:95) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:248)
... 19 more
```

Comment: Stack trace says : at test.process.test.init(test.java:73) you should watch the test.java file at line 73 to understand better what happens

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For some reason, I did not see the problem. I have checked the init method but did not realize that a value inside this method remained null. Now I have to find out why the variable isn't filled, but at least I know where to look. Thank you for the new perspective I apparently needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue, it was a database problem which resulted in an empty object, which caused the initial NullpointerException. The other exceptions were a consequence of the Nullpointer. With the object filled, the war deployed correctly.